# Close thread while closing form

Tags: c#, multithreading, objectdisposedexception

I do my first tries in c#. In my application a new Fom is created to show some measurements. i do this in a thread. on form closing i will exit the thread. sometimes it throws a ObjectDisposedException exception. i tried to handle it with a mutex. but then i have a dead lock.

```
private void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    m_mutClosing.WaitOne();
    bDoWork = false;
    m_mutClosing.ReleaseMutex();
}


    public void DoWork()
    {
        while (bDoWork)
        {
            i++;

            m_mutClosing.WaitOne();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                if(textBox != null)
                    textBox.Text = i.ToString();
            });
            m_mutClosing.ReleaseMutex();

            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("end thread");
    }
```

the problem seems like i try to write a value to the textbox until the objects get removed.

I don´t see the solution in the other question, can please someone explain?

Comment: It could be happening because of the Thread.Sleep(500) is occurring at FormClosing.

Comment: Cold rock-hard rule: *never* block the UI thread.  Guaranteed to deadlock here on the Invoke() call, it cannot complete unless the UI thread is idle.  You don't need Invoke at all, BeginInvoke is fine.

Comment: have you tried `Dispatcher.Invoke()` for thread? UI is in main thread so you must use `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` to connect this threads

Comment: it is my first time programming c#, can you please give me some more code? thanks a lot